# How to editText.setText(integer) in inflated tablerow layout (Android)

Tags: android, integer, decimal, textfield

I've got a editText field. In this field, I've defined: android:inputType="numberDecimal"

In my code I've a button that has to be set the value of the editText. The value is an integer. I am doing this by: text.setText(saved);

But when I press the button, my app crashes. But I cant figure out why. It has to be something simple, but I can't figure it out. Someone who understands why the program crashes and what I have to do to fix it?

I have already tried it to convert it to a String, or using ""+saved, and some other simple basic tricks.

This is my log:

This is my code (All in the main activity):

```
public void onFetchOpenTimesheetsClick(View v) {
    newSavedData();
}

public void onFetchNewTimesheetsClick(View v) {
    addTableRow();
}

public void addAddTimesheetTableRow() {
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.mainTable);
    table.removeAllViews();
    TableRow row =     (TableRow)LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.additem, null);
    table.addView(row);
    table.requestLayout();
    restoreSavedData();
}

public void restoreSavedData() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    int saved = settings.getInt("savedData", 0);
    EditText text = (EditText)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    text.setText(saved);
}

 public void newSavedData() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    EditText text = (EditText)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.editText;
    int toSave = Integer.valueOf(text.getText().toString());
    editor.putInt("savedData", toSave);
    editor.commit();
}
```

The relevant XML data in my XML file:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >
</EditText>
```

Comment: I am on it, one second ;-)

Comment: did you initialize your `EditText` before setting?

Comment: Yes I did with: EditText text = (EditText)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.editText);

Comment: so please post your Code and `logCat`

Comment: Code posted, how do I post logCat?

Comment: @PGriep by editing your question and post the relevant xml also

Comment: @PGriep in ddms perspective you see the logcat. there is button at the top right if you are usign eclipse. Select the excpetion part extract it to textfile. Copy paste the same here

Comment: Declare your  TableRow row as class variable 
and instead of this "EditText text = (EditText)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.editText);"

use "EditText text = (EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.editText);"

Comment: @PGriep what is the name of the xml in which you have edtitext??? s it in activity xml or `additem.xml`.

Comment: Cant format the logCat in stackoverflow, i am working on that. additem.xml is the xml file where editText is in.

Comment: @PGriep then you need `TableRow row =     (TableRow)LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.additem, null);` and then  `EditText text = (EditText)row..findViewById(R.id.editText)` as `findViewById` looks for a view in the current inflated layout. hence the NPE

Comment: Where to add it? And does it work for the multiple added rows?

Comment: @PGriep post the full xml layout. you need to provide more info. relevant xml in which you have the editttext and the stacktrace.

Comment: Provided you already, thats the whole part of the xml where editText is defined. You have also got all the code that is used. My other code is irrelevant. It seems that when I try to setText, my program does not know that editText exist. I've multiple rows (set by addAddTimesheetTableRow() that inflates the same xml file which has the editText in it.

Comment: @PGriep i still don't see what is `addItem.xml` the one with edittext or one with table row? where is table layout and table row. So its really confusing.

Comment: Tablelayout is in main.xml. Tablerow is in additem.xml. Foreach data line found in the retrieved data, there is a tablerow added. In this tablerow you have the editText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was simple. I've added a simple loop in my two save methods. This is to check each row for save data and load data. The problem I had before was because I had multiple rows with one xml layout. Therefor you need some extra coding to know each editText. You can see my solution below:

```
public void restoreSavedData() {
    // Restore preferences
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.mainTable);
    for(int n = 0, s = table.getChildCount(); n < s; ++n) {
        TableRow row = (TableRow)table.getChildAt(n);
        EditText text = (EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        int saved = settings.getInt(String.valueOf(n), 0);
        try {
            text.setText(String.valueOf(saved));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void newSavedData() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.mainTable);
    int toSave = 0;
    for(int n = 0, s = table.getChildCount(); n < s; ++n) {
        TableRow row = (TableRow)table.getChildAt(n);
        EditText text = (EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        if(!text.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            toSave = Integer.valueOf(text.getText().toString());
            editor.putInt(String.valueOf(n), toSave);
            // Commit the edits!
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the data of each row is saved and loaded when needed.

Answer (score 2):

> In my code I've a button that has to be set the value of the editText.
>   The value is an integer

use

```
text.setText(String.valueOf(saved));
```

`setText()` looks for a resource with the id if not found you get `ResourceNotFoundException`. Resource id is an `int`. So you are looking for `setText(CharacterSequence);`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)

`findViewById` looks for a view with the current inflated inflated layout. If not you end up with `NullPointerException`. `EditText` is in a different layout than the one set to activity. So if you inflate that layout you need to use the inflated view object to initialize your edittext.

I guess you want add edittext to table row. I guess you ahve a table layout to  which you want to add rows with edittext

Declare `EditText ed` as a instance variable

```
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.mainTable);
    table.removeAllViews();
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    ed = new EditText(this); 
    row.addView(ed);
    table.addView(row);
    table.requestLayout();
```

Comment: @PGriep post some more code and the stacktrace for further help

Comment: @PGriep what do you see in logcat what is the excpetion?? what is saved? an int value??

Comment: The log says there is a NullPointerException. But when I am in debug mode, I see that the integer is filled. So, why the NullPointerException?

Comment: @PGriepmpost the full stacktrace and the activity code without which it is not possible to pin point the mistake

Answer (score 1):

try this way `text.settext(""+saved);`
where saved is your `int`.

Here is a test code i tried now which works for me

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:text="Button" /></LinearLayout>
```

And the class file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button btn;
private EditText edit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (edit.getText().toString().length() > 0)
                btn.setText("" + edit.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: +1. If you try to set an int, it will look for the ressource mapped for this int.

Answer (score 0):

please do like this

```
int value;//whatever the value is
TextView data = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
data .setText(Integer.toString(value));
```